# Subclass factory missing prototype - Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, subclassing

I'm trying to create a factory function which accepts a superclass and a function as arguments, and returns a constructor for a subclass which overrides and applies a filter to the add() method.

The problem I'm getting is when I use this constructor to create this subclass object and invoke add(), the add() method isn't recognised.

If it helps I'm trying to use techniques similar to section 9.7.2 from Javascript - The definitive guide by David Flanagan.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

```
function subclassFactory(superclass,func){
     var constructor = function(){
        superclass.apply(this,arguments);    

        var proto = constructor.prototype 
                  = Object.create(superclass.prototype);
        proto.constructor = constructor; 

        proto.add = function(){
             if(!func(arguments)) 
             {
              return superclass.prototype.add.apply(this,arguments);
             } 
         }
     }

     return constructor;
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind showing code example of using `subclassFactory` for an object where `add()` isn't being recognised?

Comment: You mistakenly have the manipulation of `constructor.prototype` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the prototype inside the constructor.

<s>And please (as a rule of thumb) never ever pass the arguments-object to any function.</s> *You'd want to avoid passing the arguments-object to another function.*
It prevents the optimization through the underlying JS-engine. Use the spread-operator instead (ES6 [Rest parameters @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)) or copy the Arguments manually into an Array.

```
function subclassFactory(superclass, func){
    var constructor = function(/*...args*/){
        //for(var i=arguments.length,args=Array(i);i--;)args[i]=arguments[i];
        //return superclass.apply(this, args);
        return superclass.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    constructor.prototype = Object.create(superclass.prototype, { 
        constructor: { 
            configurable: true, 
            value: constructor 
        },
        add: { 
            value: function(/*...args*/){
                for(var i=arguments.length,args=Array(i);i--;)args[i]=arguments[i];
                if(!func(args)) return superclass.prototype.add.apply(this, args);
            }
        }
    });

    return constructor;
}
```

Or utilizing ES6-Classes ([Classes#Mix-ins @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins))

```
var subclassFactory = (superclass, func) => class extends superclass {
    add(...args){  
        if(!func(args)) return super.add.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "never ever" is too drastic. It's not as bad in strict mode (which you're using for sure?), it just requires instantiation of the object that could otherwise be optimised away - but something needs to be instantiated anyway to be passed around. Certainly in your `constructor` function there's absolutely no need to create that `args` array - in fact, directly passing `arguments` to `apply` is faster.

Comment: @Bergy You live and learn. Thx. Actually I have to look that up. Everything I've read on this topic yet, suggested that touching arguments in any other way than accessing it's known properties was one of the really bad things, that would make the Engine jump through some loops to secure this task and prevent damaging or exposing the call-stack, or sth like that. If it's just another Object instantiation, that's ridiculous. Has passing arguments generally that little impact, or does this only apply here to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the very first time you call `subclassPrototype` and the `superclass` variable does not have an `add` method in its prototype chain:

```
var parent = subclassFactory(function () {}, function(args) { ... }),
    child = subclassFactory(parent, function(args) { ... }),
    childInstance = new child();

child.add(...); // throws an exception
```

Solutions:

1. Check for the add method first before calling it
2. Always pass in a super class object that defines `add` somewhere in its prototype chain
3. Check if an add method in the `superClass` prototype and throw an error if one doesn't exist
4. If the "add" method doesn't exist on the super class, default it to an empty function